# use the like command in MySQLi and php for a datetime field

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I am attempting to run a query based on a date to get everything changed today, however the field that has the date is a datetime field, which I can't change.  The value in my date_modified field looks like 2013-10-25 07:05:43.  I know the query works without the date.  If I just use Navicat and run the query's where clause as:

```
WHERE  inventory.date_modified like '2013-10-25%'
```

It runs fine. I found a few ideas in other SO posts and when I try to put it into my php code as:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");  $today = '%' . $today . '%';
```

and then my where clause is:

```
WHERE inventory.date_modified like $today
```

I get the fatal error of trying to parse a non object. I know there is a value in $today, but I am unclear how to do this with my php code?

Comment: Why do you think a LIKE query would work? Why wouldn't you simply query for `date_modified BETWEEN '2013-10-25 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-25 23:59:59'`?

Comment: The date is always going to change, which is why I was using a variable.

Comment: And? LIKE still won't work. Modify the example given with your variable, just add the time information so you get everything between midnight and 23:59:59 - that represents one day.

Comment: this worked perfectly.  If you want to put it as an answer I would be happy to mark it as the one that I used.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but it's sufficient for me that the comment helped you, there is an answer provided by Glavić which is just fine so please mark his as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution was the [N.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693806/n-b)'s in the question comment. Because, if you have index on field `date_modified`, it will be used.

So, if you have date formated as `Y-m-d`, like you have in `$today`, you can do:

```php
$sql = "
    ...
    WHERE inventory.date_modified BETWEEN '$today 00:00:00' AND '$today 23:59:59'
    ...
";
```

Another example would be, to use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, to get date part from datetime:

```php
$sql = "
    ...
    WHERE DATE(inventory.date_modified) = '$today'
    ...
";
```

**but**, this example is not good if you have index on field `date_modified`, because it will be ignored, and whole table will be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

You Forget to set the quotes on database value:

```
WHERE inventory.date_modified like '$today'
```

Comment: I get an error of unexpected t variable when i try this, any other ideas?

Comment: Show me how you build the WHERE clause in PHP.

Comment: WHERE inventory.date_modified like '$today' limit 0, 100

Comment: I mean if you use single or double quotes to encapsulate the string: `$where = "WHERE inventory.date_modified like '{$today}'";` should work.

Comment: and then just use $where as my WHERE clause?  I am using single quotes around my entire query.

Comment: Yes :) It would be really helpful if you post the complete sql build, so it's easier to show you the problem ;)

The Problem with single quotes is that PHP didn't search for variables to replace in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
 $today = '2013-10-25';

 SELECT * FROM inventory  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(inventory.date_modified, "%Y-%m-%d") = $today;
```